# Pino logger: how to keep log in dynamically created folders

Tags: node.js, logging, pinojs

In my project, there is an option for creating apps.
Based on app Id, I need to create folder named **app Id** and keep trace.log, out.log etc files separately. For logging, pino is used for that.

```
let dir = process.env.LOG_FILE_PATH+"/"+appId;
!fs.existsSync(dir) && fs.mkdirSync(dir);
logger = pino({
    level: level,
    customLevels: {
        perf: 25,
        audit: 28
    },
    timestamp: pino.stdTimeFunctions.isoTime,
    
},
pino.destination(dir+"/trace.log")
);
```

Is there any way to create log folder based on condition and keep the logs files within it.